# OctoberCMS Fileupload completely destroys my backend

Tags: laravel, file-upload, plugins, backend, octobercms

I was (and i'm) getting issues with the fields.yaml -> type fileupload, I already put on the `$attachOne -> 'upfile' => ['System\Models\File']` but it completely destroys my backend. Probably the problem is on create.htm.

Here is a screenshot -> WITHOUT `$attachOne -> 'upfile' => ['System\Models\File']` :=> https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQQjO.png WITH `$attachOne -> 'upfile' => ['System\Models\File']` :=> https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhABj.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem, on my

> create.htm

there was a extra line of code like this `<style media="screen"> </style>`. All nice and running now.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. The `fileupload` form field type expects a relationship definition. As shown in your own texts, when you have it included, there is no issue. When you remove it, it throws an exception.

Comment: I have the fields.yaml with the corrent indentation (i know YAML is picky about it). It still push is makup beyond the borders.